# HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse on WP8

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8, httpwebresponse, portable-class-library

I have a problem with WebRequest in a PCL (Portable Class Library) again.

I have this piece of code:

```
    static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    static string doc;

    static public void AddAnime(string encodedLogin, string id, int episodes, int status, int score)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodedLogin))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        else
        {   
            doc = String.Format("anime_id={0}&status={1}&episodes={2}&score={3}", id, "watching", episodes, score);

            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://mal-api.com/animelist/anime");

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = encodedLogin;

            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestCallBack), request);

            allDone.WaitOne();

            s.ToString();
        }
    }

    static private void GetRequestCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)aResult.AsyncState;

        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(aResult);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(doc);

        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, doc.Length);
        postStream.Flush();

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }

    static private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        string responseString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        //Do something with string here

        allDone.Set();
    }
```

Now, the problem is, when I call `AddAnime` in a sample Console app, this runs perfectly fine, but when I call it from my WP8 device or emulator (WXGA), it gets stuck on `BeginGetResponse`. It doesn't enter `GetResponseCallback` at all (tested with breakpoints), and doesn't continue with any code directly after `BeginGetResponse` either. I've waited for more than two minutes, which should throw a `TimeOutException` (I think), but even then nothing at all happened.

I tested with:

- Console app (works)
- WP8 WXGA emulator (doesn't work)
- WP8 Device connected (doesn't work)
- WP8 Device disconnected (doesn't
  work)

For my PCL I target:

- SL4 and higher
- WP7 and higher
- Windows Store
- .NET 4.5

How could I solve this? Isn't a PCL used to guarantee cross-compatibility?

Comment: SideNote: Why don't you use TPL (async/await) such as `request.GetResponseAsync()`? Your code could be simpler and easy to maintain.

Comment: TPL Takes a little while to get used to, but it is awesome

Comment: I would love to, but how do I use that within a Portable Class Library that targets SL4, WP7.1, WP8 and Windows Store?

Comment: @FedorFinkenflugel It seems you introduce new restrictions which were not mentioned in your question

Comment: Added them to the original question, I forgot to mention it

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone (and Silverlight, I think), explicitly prevent you from waiting for the result of a network operation on the UI thread.  You need to return control of the thread to the caller- if you try to block on it then you'll deadlock.

The easiest way to do this is with Tasks and async/await.  We've released an [Async Targeting Pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx) which adds this support to the platforms you're targeting (and Portable Class Libraries targeting them).  Note that Windows Phone 7.0 isn't supported, you'll need to choose Windows Phone 7.1/7.5 (it's the same thing but different places use a different version number).